# Load layout and webview same time

Tags: android, android-layout

When the app passes from one activity to another which contains a webview, it is visible that the layout is loaded first and then the web view. Is there a way to force the webview to load same time as the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to load the `layout` same time as the `Webview`.
You should add an event listener on the `onPageFinished`. For example, you'll have something like that:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Load your layout here
    }
});
```

You now have to load the layout at this time. For example, when your `Activity` starts, just hide both your `layout` and your `Webview`. Then, as soon as the page has been loaded, change them both to visible and you are done.